# sql express visual interface in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-express, localdb

I am using a SQL express databases in Visual studio 2013.But when i connect to sql express, open server explorer and trying to create a table, i see visual interface  sql server db .Any adуas?

Comment: Unsure what you are asking, but SQL Server = SQL Server Express = SQL Server Express LocalDB in VS terms

Comment: same question http://forums.asp.net/p/2037163/5867352.aspx?Re+sql+express+visual+interface+in+visual+studio+2013